# iOS 5 Mobile Safari application cache changes?

Tags: javascript, ios5, mobile-safari, offline, application-cache

I'm wondering if anyone has run into new problems with using the HTML5 application cache in Mobile Safari on iOS 5 devices? I had previously written an offline web app that worked well in iOS 4, but as devices that use this app are being moved over to iOS 5, I am discovering problems when devices are offline and attempting to access what should be cached resources.

I can confirm that the application caching procedure is working as expected, as I can track the hits to my webserver as resources are downloaded while the device is online.

The problem manifests itself in the form of the "Cannot Open Page: Safari cannot open the page because it is not connected to the Internet" dialog box when I attempt to follow a link to a page that *should* be cached while I am offline.

Interestingly, around the same time this error pops up, in the Debug Console one also gets the "JavaScript execution exceeded timeout" error, similar to what is mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787219/javascript-ios5-javascript-execution-exceeded-timeout). I'm not doing any computation nearly as complicated as what was posted there, but the suggestion to kill and restart Safari seems to fix both problems, at least for now.

So maybe this question is less a request for help and more of a landing place for future searchers to share their experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have added the cached page itself into the manifest file, in below example they are HTMLPage1.htm & HTMLPage2.htm. I have the same problem but it works after adding the cached page link.

CACHE MANIFEST
CACHE:
images/cover.png
**HTMLPage1.htm

HTMLPage2.htm**

NETWORK:
*