# OpenLaszlo 4.9.0 DHTML app on iOS 4.3.5: JavaScript execution exceeded timeout

Tags: javascript, iphone, dhtml, openlaszlo, lzx

I'm unable to load my OpenLaszlo application on iPhone (but able on iPad). When I run the Debug Console, the following error is reported:

JavaScript execution exceeded timeout. (LFCdhtml.js)

I'm running OpenLaszlo 4.9.0, DHTML Runtime.

Has anyone else run into this error? If so, how can I refactor my code so that I can avoid it? Other folks running into this error doing web development have suggested breaking down JavaScript execution in smaller parts:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787988

If I know the corresponding areas in my LZX file that I should break into parts, then I could follow the same approach.

Comment: This occurs on iOS 4.3.5 but not iOS 6.0.

Comment: What happens if you kill all apps and restart Safari? Do you still see the same error? And do you see any error messages in the debug console?

Comment: Modified the title to reflect that the problem occurs with iOS 4.3.5; Added the tag [tag:lzx].

Comment: Did you find any solution besides upgrading to a newer version of iOS? It might be a bug in Safari on iOS as well, and it would be good to have an answer to this question - even it that is "It's an iOS bug and there's no workaround".