# JavaScript execution exceeded timeout javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, settimeout

when I execute this function it displays me the following error:

"JavaScript execution exceeded timeout" how I can solve this problem by using settimeout () or what?

I retrieve 3000 line from  json file.

```
 applyChanges_PhrasesTypes: function(employees, callback) {

            //alert("fonction apply chamges est lancer PhrasesTypes");

          this.db.transaction(
                function(tx) {
                    var l = employees.length;
                    var sql =
                        "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO PhrasesTypes (IdPhrase, IdPhraseES, IdRubrique, IdTypeTravauxAffichage, Phrase, AidePhrase, AvertissementPhrase,OrdrePhrase,QuotationParDefaut,Published) " +
                        "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                    //alert('Inserting or Updating in local database:  PhrasesTypes');
                    var e;
                    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) 
                    {
                        e = employees[i];
                        log(i);
                        //log("Ligne  "+ i +"  est inserer de id PhrasesTypes = "+e.IdPhrase);
                        var params = [e.IdPhrase, e.IdPhraseES, e.IdRubrique, e.IdTypeTravauxAffichage, e.Phrase, e.AidePhrase, e.AvertissementPhrase,e.OrdrePhrase,e.QuotationParDefaut,e.Published];
                        tx.executeSql(sql, params);
                    }
                    log('sync_PhrasesType shronization terminée avec (' + l + ' items sync_PhrasesTypeshronié)');
                },
                this.txErrorHandler_PhrasesTypes,
                function(tx)
                {
                    callback();
                }
            );
        }
```

---

@lgor: here is my code but only 2000 insert line, and terminates with an error,

JavaScript execution exceeded timeout javascript

```
 InsertPortion: function(tx)
    {
     var l = Math.min(gEmployees.length, gIter + 300);

     log('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa---'+l)

     for (; gIter<l ; gIter++)
                {
         log('do insert here'); 
          var sql =
             "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO PhrasesTypes (IdPhrase, IdPhraseES, IdRubrique, IdTypeTravauxAffichage, Phrase, AidePhrase, AvertissementPhrase,OrdrePhrase,QuotationParDefaut,Published) " +
             "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
         //alert('Inserting or Updating in local database:  PhrasesTypes');
                var e;            
             e = gEmployees[gIter];
             log(gIter);
             //log("Ligne  "+ i +"  est inserer de id PhrasesTypes = "+e.IdPhrase);
             var params = [e.IdPhrase, e.IdPhraseES, e.IdRubrique, e.IdTypeTravauxAffichage, e.Phrase, e.AidePhrase, e.AvertissementPhrase,e.OrdrePhrase,e.QuotationParDefaut,e.Published];
             tx.executeSql(sql, params);

                  }

                if (gIter < gEmployees.length)
                {
                    log('sync_PhrasesType shronization terminée avec (' + gIter+ ' items sync_PhrasesTypeshronié)');
                    setTimeout(dao3.InsertPortion(tx), 100);
                } 
                else
                {
                   gEmployees = null; 
                   gIter = 0;
                }

   },




applyChanges_PhrasesTypes: function(employees, callback) {

        //alert("fonction apply chamges est lancer PhrasesTypes");

      this.db.transaction(
            function(tx)
            {
                gIter = 0;
                gEmployees = employees;

                dao3.InsertPortion(tx);

            },
            this.txErrorHandler_PhrasesTypes,
            function(tx)
            {
                callback();
            }
        );
    },
```

Comment: I just hope you don't run that SQL stored in JavaScript into a database. Major security issue.

Comment: @jfrej That could be SQL used on a HTML5 local storage SQLlite database.

Comment: sorry but I can not have you understand

Comment: yes I am trying to use sqlite

Comment: @AaminerZeajejk What line is that error occurring on? Also, this can't be the entire code, since `this.db` isn't defined anywhere. Can we have more code?

Comment: about this.db: no I just copy part of my code

Comment: after having insert 2645  line, the script stops and shows me error message "JavaScript execution exceeded timeout"

Comment: If it is taking too long for your javascript to execute in a tight "for" loop, you can split the work into smaller portions, and execute them one at a time triggering these executions using setTimeout. Look up how setTimeout javascript function is used and ask if you need help setting it up.

Comment: @lgor :  yes i need help setting it up, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [javascript-ios5-javascript-execution-exceeded-timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787219/javascript-ios5-javascript-execution-exceeded-timeout)

Comment: @jfrej : sorry, I did not understand

Comment: @jlogr:

how can i split the work into smaller portions, because 
{ var l = employees.length; } is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the loops in your code to async calls.
Take a look at https://github.com/caolan/async