# what are the limitations of WKWebview/UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, html, hybrid-mobile-app, wkwebview

I am trying to find the limiations of WKWebView/UIWebView I couldn't find much even though there are

What is the maximum size of image it can load ? such as 4mb

What is the maximum audio/video file size it can play ?

What is the javascript execution timeout ?

What is the size of page it can load without any memory leak ?

Comment: @KiritModi - It's not explaining the limitations

Comment: From what I've seen and based on personal experience, WKWebView is plagued with memory leaks. They seem to be related to loading text inputs and attempting to type in them. Each time it happens, a little bit of memory leaks, and at the moment, there is no fix. Since it is a bug in UIKit itself, Apple will need to fix it in order for it to not leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the size of page it can load without any memory leak ?

- depends on how you handle it and the target device in which the UIWebView runs even then it will generate a memory warning not a leak if used properly.

> What is the javascript execution timeout ?

- Unknown arbitrary value, no reference of such values mentioned anywhere. You can set timeouts to your requests though. [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787219/javascript-ios5-javascript-execution-exceeded-timeout).

Comment: If you could get me some official reference guideline also it'd be helpful